# Retornar un tag dentro de una funcion React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

tengo esta función donde analizo si un string esta dentro de un subarray de un json, cuando lo encuentra tiene que crear un marcador en el mapa pero el problema es que no lo retorna en el mapa, si me meto a la consola me aparece el marcador que intento retornar pero como dije anteriormente no se ve renderiza en el mapa. ¿Cuál puede ser el error?

Funcion:

```
checkCategories = (valorItem, array) => {
    if(this.props.seleccion){
        for(var i=0; i < array.length ; i++){
            //console.log(array[i].Categoria)
            if(array[i].Categoria.indexOf(this.props.categoria)===0){
                console.log(<Marker key={valorItem.id} position={{ lat: valorItem.latitud, lng: valorItem.longitud }} icon={icon_client} />)
                return <Marker key={valorItem.id} position={{ lat: valorItem.latitud, lng: valorItem.longitud }} icon={icon_client} />
            }else{
                return false
            }
        }
    }else{
        console.log("nada")
    }
        // console.log(obj);
};
```

llamo a la función en esta parte del codigo:

```
 <Map
                    containerStyle={containerStyle}
                    initialCenter={center}
                    sylte={style}
                    zoom={3}
                    google={this.props.google}
                    disableDefaultUI
                    >
                        {
                            this.props.proveedores ? this.props.providers.map(valorItem => {this.checkCategories(valorItem, valorItem.categorias)})
                                : 
                            console.log(this.props.categoria)
                        }
                        
                        <InfoWindow marker={this.state.activeMarker} visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}>
                                <div>
                                    <h4>{this.state.selectedPlace.name}</h4>
                                </div>
                        </InfoWindow>                                
                    </Map>
```

Comment: Comó llamas `checkCategories` en tu codigó?

Comment: ¿Has probado a meter el return dentro de divs?

Comment: @milmal ahi agregue el codigo en donde hago el llamado a la funcion, esta dentro de un map para ver si dentro de las categorias de 1 item contienen el string que estoy buscando

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que retornas la función adentro de `{}`.

React no puede mostrar HTML adentro una función que no retorna nada.
Ejemplo: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-aryabhata-5i3vf?file=/src/App.js)

```
const unObjecto = () => {
  return <p>Hola</p>;
};

export default function App() {
  const lista1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  const lista2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {
        // no se mostrará
        lista1
          ? lista1.map((num) => {
              unObjecto();
            })
          : null
      }

      {
        // se mostrará
        lista2 ? lista2.map((num) => unObjecto()) : null
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Nesecitas escribir:

```
{this.props.proveedores
        ? this.props.providers.map((valorItem) => this.checkCategories(valorItem, valorItem.categorias))
        : console.log(this.props.categoria)}
```

O escribir un `return` adentro la función:

```
{this.props.proveedores
        ? this.props.providers.map((valorItem) => { return this.checkCategories(valorItem, valorItem.categorias); })
        : console.log(this.props.categoria)}
```